# Using an flash MP3 player (any one) on Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can someone teach me how to embed a flash MP3 player (step-by-step) using codeigniter?  I have been trying for hours now with no success.  I am so frustrated.  Someone please help me.  Thanks.

Comment: This question is pretty vague... What's not working? What have you tried, what are you doing? Is it a question about accessing the mp3s from the flash file, or don't you know how to embed flash to start with.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple one I've come across is the [Yahoo! Media Player](http://mediaplayer.yahoo.com/). It's Javascript based rather than Flash, but it still gives the user a nice interface.

It scans the page looking for links to MP3 files and loads them into the player, and degrades nicely in the absence of Javascript.